# HTML Displaying value of a <div> as suffixed text in another <div> in HTML

Tags: html, css

I am trying to merge and display Text with value from another `<div>` as `modal-header` but its not happening correctly. On giving a id to `modal-header`, the `*&times;*` symbol is dropped.

I have a `modal-header` like this:-

```
<div class="modal-header" style="padding-top: 5px;padding-bottom: 5px;">
    <div style="text-align: center; float:center;font-weight: bold;">
                            Summary -   
     <?php echo '<script>  return $("#show_finyear").html();</script>'; ?>
        <button class="close" type="button" style="border-radius: 40%; margin:0; border-color: blue; float: right; color:white; background-color:black;" 
               data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" 
               title="Close Dashboard" class="btn btn-block btn-warning" 
               onclick="dbHide();">&times;
        </button>
</div>
```

The other  from where value is to be copied as follows:-

```
<div class="container" style="display: none;">  
    <div id="show_finyear" style="display: none;">2017-18</div> 
</div>
```

Comment: Are you trying to invent a css rule... `float: center;` ? Moreso, you have two `class` attributes in your `button` tag: `class="close"` and `class="btn btn-block btn-warning"`

Comment: The First css is to display the text "Summary : AMWP & Special Projects -" and the second to display "x" in same-line. This is working fine. `float: center;`  is making the text place in center and class close is from the bootstrap. I am just looking for adding "2017-18" to text "Summary : AMWP & Special Projects -" .

Comment: Make your class attribute just one. You don't need more than one. Add it like so: `class="btn btn-block btn-warning close"`. BTW, `float: center` is an invalid css rule. The reason why the text is placed at the center is because of the `text-align: center`.

Comment: Ok. Thanks with the CSS guide sir. Will amend the code accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

YES!!! Got It. Just amended the Code like this

```
<div style="text-align: center; font-weight: bold;">
                            Summary  <script> document.write($("#show_finyear").html());</script>
    <button class="close" type="button" style="border-radius: 40%; margin:0; border-color: blue; float: right; color:white; background-color:black;" data-toggle="tooltip"
                                    data-placement="bottom" title="Close Dashboard" class="btn btn-block btn-warning" 
                                    onclick="dbHide();">&times;
   </button>
</div>
```